# Sitewide jQuery functions that reference model properties

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using jQuery functions in a single page, similar to below:

```
//change the Office dropdown list when the Site selection changes
    $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#SiteID').change(function () {
                var officeUrl = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "Admin/GetJsonObjectsFromOffices";
                var ddlsource = "#SiteID";
                //get the office list
                $.getJSON(officeUrl, { SiteID: $(ddlsource).val() }, function (data) {
                    var items = "";
                    $("#OfficeID").empty();
                    $.each(data, function (i, office) {
                        items += "<option value='" + office.value + "'>" + office.text + "</option>";
                    });
                    $('#OfficeID').html(items);

                    //set the select default for Office dropdown
                    addSelectOption("OfficeID");

                    //set the site selection based on model data
                    $('#OfficeID').val(@Model.OfficeID);

                    updateSiteName();
                });
            });

            function updateSiteName(){
                var dropdownSelection = document.getElementById("SiteId");
                var siteName = dropdownSelection.options[dropdownSelection.selectedIndex].text;
                document.getElementById("SiteName").value = siteName;
            }
});
```

Ideally, I would like to put this in a sitewide .js file so that I don't have to include it in every page. I would reference the script in the `<head>` of my `_Layout.cshtml` file

```
<script src="~/js/site.js"></script>
```

The problem is, when I include it like this it no longer works. I get a squiggly line on the `@Model.OfficeID` line, as the .js file has no model to reference. Is there a way to write this once and include it in all my pages rather than separately in each?

Comment: `@Url.Content()` and `@Model.OfficeID` are razor code. Razor is not parsed in external files. You would need to include those values in the main view (say) as `data-` attributes in the element your handling so you can access them in the external script

Comment: For example `<select data-officeurl="@Url.Action(...)" data-defaultid="@Model.OfficeID" ..... >` (and use `Url.Action(), not Url.Content()`)

Answer (score 0):

Yes

You want to have that @Model.OfficeId value on many pages, means you have a layout page or a commonly share page.

If point 1 is OK then creat a hidden input element in shared.cshtml(any shared cshtml file) and set the value through your common base controller or where you are getting it.

```
<input id="officeID" type="hidden" value="@Model.OfficeID" />
```

Once set, you can use the value of using $('#officeId').val() anywhere you are inside that share.cshtml file.